# How can I split the dictionaries of a list in different lines with Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, split

It turns out that I have a list, which is composed of several dictionaries. What I intend is to copy that list into a JSON file, witheach dictionary split into a different line. Since they are independent dictionaries. I only manage to copy the list with all its dictionaries followed in the file.

```
result=[dictionary1, dictionary2, dictionary3]

with open(x, 'r') as infile:
   result.append(json.load(infile))

with open('Mergedjson.json', 'w') as output_file:
   json.dump(result, output_file)
```

This returns the file to me in the following way:

> [dictionary1, dictionary2, dictionary3]

and I intend to get the following:

> ```
> dictionary1
> dictionary2 
> dictionary3
> ```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over the list and dump it. Note that you need a newline character, otherwise it just appends the dict on the same line.

```
with open('Mergedjson.json', 'w') as output_file:
    for dct in result:
        json.dump(dct, output_file)
        output_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: True. Thank you very much. I had not realized that way. But I do not understand why I get this error back. Do you know why?                                                                                     
`raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
JSONDecodeError: Extra data`

Comment: I cannot tell how ``Extra data`` is related to this problem as you have not mentioned it before.